# How can I fix Ubuntu screen goes blank?

Tags: boot, radeon

We have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on an ASUS F83SE.

During installation we pressed <kbd>F6</kbd> to use `nomodeset` and also set `acpi` to `off`.

Now that Ubuntu 12.04 has installed, the screen goes blank.

How can we overcome this problem?

The system's specifications:

- Intel(R)Core 2 duo CPU T6600 @2.2O GHz
- ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4570
- 4GB RAM

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I just wanted to let you know that I have edited your question title to be more descriptive of the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can revert to the terminal with ctrl alt F1 (go back with ctrl alt f7) and check the logs with dmesg and cat /var/log/syslog to check what is going wrong.